# GTK+ : keyword can't be an expression

Tags: gtk

this works ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, time
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject
[ .. ]
class MyClass(Gtk.Window):
 def __init__(self):
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self ,title="My First Class")
```

but when I want to also set the default dimensions, it comes bleating:

```
import sys, os, time
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject
[ .. ]
class MyClass(Gtk.Window):
 def __init__(self):
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self ,title="My First Class" ,default-width='800' ,default-height='600')
```

will produce a "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"
I have already type the parameters with single or double quotes, or with none, it doesn't make a difference. Setting other parameters like "resizable" or "decorated" works fine, though.

What am I missing?
Where is there a tutorial or a list of examples that I could have followed to avoid this issue?

TIA,

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want `default_width` instead of `default-width` (the expression the error message is referring to is subtracting 'width' from 'default'). The values should be integers so drop the quotes from there.